# To get the Index of a particular element, which is a sentence string present in a column of a DataFrame with conditions

Tags: python, string, indexing

I have a table. There are numbers in the column 'Para'. I have to **find the index** for a particular sentence from the column 'Country_Title in such a way that the **value at Column 'Para' is 2**.

Main DataFrame 'df_countries' is shown below:

| Index | Sequence | Para | Country_Title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 | 4 | India is seventh largest country |
| 1 | 6 | 6 | Australia is a continent country |
| 2 | 7 | 2 | Canada is the 2nd largest country |
| 3 | 9 | 3 | UAE is a country in Western Asia |
| 4 | 10 | 2 | China is a country in East Asia |
| 5 | 11 | 1 | Germany is in Central Europe |
| 6 | 13 | 2 | Russia is the largest country |
| 7 | 14 | 3 | Capital city of China is Beijing |

> Suppose my keyword is China. And I want to get the index for the sentence with 'China', but only  the one at 'Para' = 2

> Consider the rows at index :- 4 and 7 ; both have same Country_Title. But I want to obtain the index for the one with 'Para' = 2, i.e., the result must be index = 4

**My Approach:**
I derived another DataFrame 'df_para2_countries' from above table as shown below:

| Index | Para | Country_Title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | Canada is the 2nd largest country |
| 4 | 2 | China is a country in East Asia |
| 6 | 2 | Russia is the largest country |

Now I store the country title as:

```
c = list(df_level2_countries['Country_Title'])
```

I used a for loop to parse through elements in 'c' and find the index of a particular country in the table 'df_countries'

```
for i in c:
    if 'China' in i:
          print(i)
          ind= df_para2_countries.loc[df_para2_countries['Country_Title'] = i]
          print(ind)
```

the identifier 'ind' gives error.
I want to get the index, but this doesn't work.
Please post your suggestion on how can I approach to this.

Answer (score 1):

You need two equals in your condition?

If you need only the 'index', that is, the value from your first column called index, then you can change the series returned from .loc() to a list, and then get first value, for instance:

```
ind = df_para2_countries.loc[df_para2_countries['Country_Title'] == i].to_list()[0]
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: this gives the entire row, i want only the index

Comment: I have edited the answer to get only the 'index' value, I hope it works for you but it's hard to test.